# How should I interpret "nearly" in this sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adverbs

Several stories in major news organizations (Washington Post, NPR, NY Times) today used an interesting construction in describing the alarming increase in Omicron infections: "*Omicron positives are doubling nearly every two days*" How EXACTLY should that be interpreted? Does the word "nearly" refer to the "two", or does it refer to an implicit rate?
If it refers to the "two", i.e., "nearly two", then it means a number LESS THAN two. E.g., "My son is nearly two years old" That would mean that the doubling time is LESS than every two days, for example if you have 10 cases today then in two days you might have 22 or 25 cases.

But if the "nearly" refers to an implicit rate then it means the doubling time is nearly as fast as every two days, so if you have 10 cases today then in 2 days you might have 18 cases or something like that.

Which is the correct way to interpret that sentence?

Comment: "I vote to close because you unfortunately omitted to present any question based on your own research of the meaning"   How would you propose to research how a construction is interpreted?   This does not depend on the dictionary meaning of "nearly" - it depends on whether, in common usage, the "nearly" is applied to the "two" or an implicit rate.  When I posted the same question [here](https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postsm1228851_-Doubling-nearlly-ever-two-days-.aspx#1228851) it was assumed to apply to the implicit rate.   But that's a smple of one.

Comment: @Lambie This question is not about the meaning of "nearly" - it is about whether, in common English usage, the "nearly" is applied to the word "two" or to the doubling rate.   Those two interpretations produce very different meanings of how fast the cases are doubling.  At least one reader, [here](https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postsm1228851_-Doubling-nearlly-ever-two-days-.aspx#1228851), thinks it applies to the rate.

Comment: " to indicate a high rate in this context, so nearly is to qualify that claim" You may be right, but that's my question.  I've discussed this with two (science and statistics) colleagues and we all agree that it's clumsily worded and they probably meant the RATE was nearly doubling and this construction would not pass muster in a science journal.  But my QUESTION is how native English speakers are likely to interpret it when reading it in the news.    By now I've posted this to several forums and gotten both interpretations, in equal numbers, apparently confirming the ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

The non-science English speaking public is likely to interpret this as Incidence Doubling in a little over two days. Not as fast as every two days but nearly so. That the rate is accelerating is an implicit threat and cause of fear.

Comment: No question in my mind that this is the way nearly everyone will interpret it unless they're being deliberately perverse.

Comment: 'The number of omicron positives (whatever that means: total or newly recorded infections?) is increasing exponentially, with an exponent slightly less than root 2, time being measured in days.'

Comment: The sentence by itself has nothing to do with a threat, and even less to do with (a cause of) fear.

Comment: It is a very reasonable guess that this is how most people would, as a matter of fact, understand the sentence. There is, however, nothing in the sentence that, as a matter of logic, rules out the alternative interpretation that the OP brings up. The sentence, as it stands, is ambiguous; a careful writer would avoid the ambiguity by using some alternative formulation.